# How to properly write a wrapper for lm() with dots only? (Error ..3 used in an incorrect context)

Tags: function, syntax, arguments, lm

I'm trying to build a wrapper for `lm()` with dots `...`, with partly success though. It works well just for the first two `formula=` and `data=` arguments. But for every argument that follows, it doesn't seem to work and throws an error.

What I'm doing with the result of `lm()` in the function is not the cause of the issue. It only seems to be related to using dots. So I was able to isolate the problem in this MWE:

```
lm_fun <- function(...) {
  lm(...)
  # <some other stuff>
}

lm_fun(formula=mpg ~ hp, data=mtcars)
## works fine

mtcars$w <- runif(nrow(mtcars))  ## adding weights
lm_fun(formula=mpg ~ hp, data=mtcars, weights=w)
# Error in eval(substitute(subset), data, env) : 
#   ..3 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in

lm_fun(formula=mpg ~ hp, data=mtcars, subset=am == 1)
# Error in eval(substitute(subset), data, env) : 
#   ..3 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in

lm_fun(formula=mpg ~ hp, data=mtcars, subset=am == 1, weights=w)
# Error in eval(extras, data, env) : 
#   ..4 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in
```

It seems to be a different issue than [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2287374/6574038) because I provide the complete set of arguments in the function call and don't add something in the function.

Am I missing something? What's the reason for this behavior, and how can I get this to work properly?

### Edit

*@user63230* offered a [nice workaround below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68209228/6574038). However, it won't work in an `lapply`, which would be important for my needs.

```
lm_fun2 <- function(...) eval(substitute(lm(...)))

fo <- c(mpg ~ hp, mpg ~ am)

lapply(fo, lm_fun, data=mtcars)
# works

lapply(fo, lm_fun2, data=mtcars)
# Error in stats::model.frame(formula = X[[i]], data = mtcars, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
#   object 'X' not found
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the environment that `w` etc. is searched for, so if you wrap it in `eval(substitute(`, the following examples work:

```
lm_fun <- function(...) {
  result <- eval(substitute(lm(...)))
  result
}
lm_fun(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
# Call:
# lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           hp  
#    30.09886     -0.06823 

lm_fun(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, weights = w)
# Call:
# lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, weights = w)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           hp  
#    31.41313     -0.07391  

lm_fun(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, weights = w, na.action = na.omit)
# Call:
# lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, weights = w, na.action = na.omit)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           hp  
#    31.41313     -0.07391 

lm_fun(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, weights = w, na.action = na.omit, 
  singular.ok = F)
# Call:
# lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, weights = w, na.action = na.omit, 
#     singular.ok = F)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           hp  
#    31.41313     -0.07391 

lm_fun(formula=mpg ~ hp, data=mtcars, subset=am == 1, weights=w)
# Call:
# lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, subset = am == 1, weights = w)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           hp  
#    32.96650     -0.07072
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261232/passing-argument-to-lm-in-r-within-function) too. The formula is automatically associated with `df` but `weights` could be external to `df`.

Comment: The problem might be of a different nature, I remember I also tried `lm_fun(formula=mpg ~ hp, data=mtcars, weights=mtcars$w)`, and the error persists. Regardless +1 your solution seems to work beautifully as a workaround.

Comment: However this won't work so well with `eval(substitute(`: `fo <- c(mpg ~ hp, mpg ~ am);lapply(fo, lm_fun, data=mtcars)`

Comment: interesting. Although I wasn't able to do it (and ignoring my approach above), i think the solution is to capture `...` in a `list`  in the classical `R` [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function) and then unlist it some way within `lm`. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028385/can-i-remove-an-element-in-dot-dot-dot-and-pass-it-on) follows a similar thought process albeit slight different angle (they're removing an element but you want to unlist the elements).